# Custom Query Component - How to get "score" from document id?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm writing several Solr Custom Query Components.
Each component run different kinds of queries:

- Component A: does a group by query  field A
- Component B: does a group by on a different fild B

Each component will send it's the documents from it's result to the next component.

In my "process" function, I'm donig the following after the result is set by grouping:

```
IndexSchema schema = searcher.getSchema();
DocListAndSet s = result.getDocListAndSet();
DocSet s3 = s.docSet;
DocIterator dit = s3.iterator()
while (dit.hasNext())
{
    SolrDocument doc = new SolrDocument();
    int docid = dit.nextDoc();
    //float score = dit.score();<--This does not get the score

    Document luceneDoc = searcher.doc(docid);//get the document using the doc id
    for( Fieldable field : luceneDoc.getFields())
    {
        SchemaField sf = schema.getField( field.name() );
        doc.addField( field.name(), sf.getType().toObject( field ) );
        ......

   }
```

And then iterating through the Set and createing SolrDocument.

The SolrDocumentes are entered into a SolDocumentList and end I send it off to the next Component:

```
rb.req.getContext().put("TAG", list);
```

I also want to add a field called "score" SolrDocument, this field will contain the actual score. I've tried getting the score using:

```
float score = dit.score()
```

But the above does not get the score of the document. How do I get the "score" of the document using the document id?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you are getting the `docSet` instead of the `docList`?

I would try (condensing a bit) getting `s.docList.iterator()` instead of `s.docSet.iterator()`.  The latter states specifically in the [documentation here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/DocSet.html#iterator%28%29) that you can't get meaningful scores from it, where the `docList` states it may contains valid scores.

Comment: I've tried both DocList and DocSet, neither of them is showing score information. Am I missing something here?

Comment: When I sue Doclist, Line: float score = dit.score(); gives Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Looks like SolrIndexSearcher has a staic flag GET_SCORES, was I supposed to set it to anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to set GET_Scores in getDocList(query,List,Lsort,offset,maxnoofdocs,1)

Here 
    `

```
 query is your query obj
 List<Query> your filters could be null
 lsort could be null
 offset 
 maxnoofdocs integer
 1 means get score with documents`
```